# Why doesn't python openCV change colors the way I expect it to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am just starting out with opencv in python3(or any language for that matter). I am on windows 10. Here is my pip freeze:

```
numpy==1.16.0
opencv-python==4.0.0.21
Wand==0.5.0
```

I am trying to change every color pixel except for (BGR notation)[255,142,0] to black.
Here is my test code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread('referenceFont.png')
cv2.imshow('original',img)
img[np.where((img!=[255,142,0]).all(axis=2))]=[0,0,0]
cv2.imshow('remove other colors',img)
img[np.where((img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))]=[0,0,0]
cv2.imshow('explicit remove white',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note that the image did originally have transparency, if that matters. I thought not loading with transparency would help simplify things.
Here is the output:

[image: output]

As you can see, just trying to change the non matching colors results in an almost unreadable image, and even when I explicitly remove white there is still a "halo effect".  I'd basically like the original image, but with a black background. Thanks for any help.

**update 1**

Per request, here is the original file.

[image: original file]

Comment: Can you attach original input image ?

Comment: it should be attached. The one all the way to the left is the one you are looking for @ZdaR

Comment: Yes I get it, but it would be better if you attach it separately as well, so that other people can run your code on their machines as well.

Comment: Dose the original input image has more than three colors.

Comment: @Rish The blue has some very similar colored pixels around it and the background is a blend of light colors

Comment: @ZdaR Please see the update. Apologies for the delay and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is advised to perform the color segmentation operations in HSV color range instead of BGR color range. Also it is worth noting that your input image has anti-aliasing colors, which means that it contains some pixels with diffused white and blue values. To tackle these kind of input images, we can use `cv2.inRange()` method instead of a single `==` operation for a given color.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/path/to/img.png")

mask = cv2.inRange(img, np.array([200,100,0]), np.array([255, 170, 255]))
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
final = cv2.min(img, mask)
```

[image]

To further improve the results you can use HSV color range instead of BGR color range.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing the gray to bgr conversion? I’m not well versed in hsv but I assume that you might do the conversion because the values you supply are some sort of gray, so that’s why you had to convert, but why take this indirect approach? Also could you please expand on why HSV is preferred? Thanks! @zdaR

Comment: The `GRAY2BGR` conversion is required for debugging purposes only (for `cv2.min()` to work we need both the matrices in same format which is 3 channel format). If you directly want to work with binary mask image then you can skip this step.

Comment: HSV color domain is preferred over the RGB color domain because for RGB the color information is distributed in all 3 channels, but in HSV domain the color information is stored in the H channel only, other 2 channels control the brightness and saturation, so you need to tweak only 1 channel which is H while working with HSV color domain

Answer (score 2):

Iterated over all unique RGB values the picture has and whoa!! those are too many colors actually.

[image]

@ZdaR is correct you should remove a range of colors and not just a specific color tuple. 
You can use this snippet to visualize the unique color pixels.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img=cv2.imread('Desktop/image.png')
arr=[]
for j in range(img.shape[1]):
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        arr.append([img[i,j,0],img[i,j,1],img[i,j,2]])

cols,img,j,k=np.unique(np.array(arr), axis=0),np.zeros((9192,9192,3), np.uint8),0,0
for i in cols:
    cv2.circle(img,(100+j*200,100+k*200), 85,(int(i[0]),int(i[1]),int(i[2])), -1)
    j+=1
    if j%45==0:
        k+=1
        j=0
cv2.imwrite('Desktop/colors.png',img)
```

and for extracting the blue components, similar answer as above:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img=cv2.imread('Desktop/image.png')
mask = cv2.inRange(img, np.array([200,100,0]), np.array([255, 170, 255])) #single channel mask
mask= np.dstack((mask,mask,mask)) #this just makes the mask a 3 channel image
cv2.imwrite('Desktop/colors.png',cv2.min(img, mask))
```

What cv2.min() does is "element wise comparison" which is comparing 1st channel value to 1st channel value, 2nd to 2nd and so on.

```
white_pixel=np.array([255,255,255])
mask=np.array([0,0,0])
print(cv2.min(white_pixel,mask))
#prints [[0][0][0]]

blue_pixel_of_some_shade=np.array([255,223,122])#not sure which shade is this
mask=np.array([255,255,255])
print(cv2.min(blue_pixel_of_some_shade,mask))
#prints [[255][223][122]]
```

[image]

> P.S You can also just multiply the mask with the image if the mask has
>   0s and 1s instead of 0s and 255s.